# How to adjust the width of master details screen ratio in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am using MasterDetailsBlock on my FormPage. I would like to adjust the screen width for the master and details part of the form. I had been searching around and haven't found a way to do it. The documentation seems to suggest it is doable through the SashForm, but I do not see how.

It will be great if I can use percentage ratio, like the FormAttachment style, but if that is not possible..I'm ok to fix the master and details to specific pixel also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SashForm.setWeights(int[]) to modify the weights of the master and the detail in the MasterDetailsBlock.

The weights describe the size ratio of the SashForm's parts. {1, 2} for examble would make the detail twice as wide as the master.

Comment: Add what point should I call it? I tried it before and got some error, I forgot which one; either IndexOutOfBound or IllegalArgument because the size of array did not match with number of children.

Comment: I got it working, I have to call the sashForm.setWeight() inside MasterDetailsBlock.createContent() after calling super.createContent() to make sure all master and details parts are already created so I have matching number of children in sashForm.

Answer (score 0):

In your MasterDetailBlock class, override the `registerPage()` method, set your all detail pages, then call `sashform.setweights(int [])`

Example:

```
protected void registerPages(DetailsPart part) {

    part.registerPage(MemoryBudgetImpl.class, new MemoryBudgetDetailPage());
    sashForm.setWeights(new int[]{1,3});

}
```